# Ошибка: IndexError: list index out of range [2]

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql

Есть скрипт который получает данные в формате json и после с помощью UPDATE вносит их в базу. Для некоторых данных нет значения и вылазит ошибка:
IndexError: list index out of range

и после останавливается скрипт, в запрос UPDATE я прямо так и вписал, **предварительно никакой проверки нет**

```
'UPDATE `emp` SET `name` = "' + str(json_loads['name'][0]) + '", .....
```

Как сделать чтобы это игнорировалось и скрипт продолжал работу или была предварительная проверка перед запросом и просто записывалась пустота?

Язык: python

Спасибо!

Comment: Хотел бы добавить, что проблема с выводом не одного значения, их больше 5, поэтому если покажите как сделать проверку сразу для 5, был бы очень благодарен и потом поместить их в запрос MySQL

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Есть цикл for в котором выполняется код с помощью subprocess.run, после выполнения этого кода результат загружается в json.loads и с помощью json_loads['name'][0] я получаю значение.

После этого всего идет запрос к MySQL для обновления данных

'UPDATE `emp` SET `name` = "' + str(json_loads['name'][0]) + '", .....

Проблема в том, что в массиве, с которого я пытаюсь получить данные иногда 3 значения, а иногда одно, таким образом  json_loads['name'][0] - актуально, а когда использую json_loads['name'][1], json_loads['name'][2] - пишет ошибку

Как сделать проверку до запроса к бд UPDATE?

Answer (score 1):

Классически "чтобы это игнорировалось" делается с помощью исключений (Exception). Try-except, with-as, raise и т.д.
Тут до проведения update (для одного элемента для наглядности) - в данном варианте элемент считается равным None при IndexError:

```
    try:
        str_info=str(json_loads['name'][0])
    except IndexError:
        str_info=None 
    finally:
        'UPDATE `emp` SET `name` = "' +str_info
```

Для большего количества сделайте цикл, например, с while. Так как я не знаю, как вы определяете количество элементов для запроса из базы, то мне код не написать.

Comment: Просто прямо в запросе UPDATE table SET name_1 = "'+ str(json_loads['name'][0]) + '", name_2 = "'+ str(json_loads['name'][1]) + '" ... никакие списки и тд не используются

Comment: 1) А запрос-то почему не изменить? 2) Запрос бесконечен?

Comment: 1) подскажите, каким образом? не совсем понимаю, поэтому здесь
2) нет конечно))

Comment: Я же привел пример изменённого запроса. Но не работаю с sql, потому про него ничего не скажу. Строка в скрипте так и выглядит (с многоточием): "'UPDATE `emp` SET `name` = "' + str(json_loads['name'][0]) + '", ....."? Если нет, то как?

Comment: Подскажите, каким образом можно сделать проверку и чтобы это было в переменной? 

то есть, присваивается значение json_loads['name'][1] в переменную, после идет проверка, если значения нет, то присваивается NULL, а в SQL запросе просто прописано было бы str_info

Comment: Изменил, как считаю правильным. Я не работал с БД никогда, но есть у меня подозрение, что так, как вы хотите, работать не может - вы не можете проверить содержимое БД до запроса к ней.  Поэтому проверка идет во время запроса, а при ошибке индекса обрабатывается исключение с присвоением None (или поставьте любое другое значение, если хотите). Кроме того, полагаю что в запросе тут опечатка ( "') - двойная кавычка и апостроф не составляют пару.

Comment: Спасибо вам! Подскажите, есть регулярка на php, там preg_match_all используется в котором входное значение идет, обрезается по выражению и выдается в итоге в другой переменной, что лучше использовать в python в таком случае?

Comment: Если задача решена, то просьба поставить +1 ответу и принять его (нажать на "треугольник вверх" слева от него и на галочку под этим треугольником). Это поощряет участников отвечать вам. По php - лучше создать другой запрос, я не знаю php. И описать чуть яснее, возможно ("обрезается по выражению"?). Если речь идёт об операциях со строками, то советую посмотреть тут, например: https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/stroki-funkcii-i-metody-strok.html

Comment: Я это сделал сразу же, как только вы еще 1 раз написали ответ, но мне выдает:"Спасибо за отзыв! Голоса от участников с репутацией менее 15 учитываются, но не меняют публично отображаемое значение рейтинга" 

Подскажите еще, каким образом можно сделать чтобы обработка была частями? а то я начинаю выполнять и БД просто виснет, как можно сделать чтобы выполнение было по 10 записей, например.

Comment: Подозреваю, что это уже вопрос по знанию БД. Не подскажу тогда точно. В общем, я бы каждый цикл работы с json_loads['name'][i] ограничивал по условию, чтобы i был меньше 10, потом проводил запись в БД. И так кругами. Но не спец в БД. Удачи!